# a problem i faced during learning functions in python

Tags: function, import, divide

```
`def isgreat(a,b):
    if(a>b):
        print("1st number is great")
    elif(b>a):
        print("2nd is great ") 
    else:
        print("equal")


def gmean(a,b):
    mean = (a+b)/2

    print(mean)

a=input("input 1st number")
b=input("input 2nd number")
isgreat(a,b)
gmean(a,b)`
```

in this program the line **mean = (a+b)/2** didnt work saying it was unsupported operand type.
it worked fine when i used it in a simple program

i was expecting that "/" to work as divide operator

Comment: Please do your own research first before posting a question. The error seems like a result of dividing an int and a string: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-type-for-plus-int-and-str#typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for--str-and-int